# How to programmatically extract / unzip a .7z (7-zip) file with R

Tags: r, zip, unzip, 7zip, rar

I'm trying to automate the extraction of a number of files compressed with 7-zip.  I need to automate this process, because a) there are many years of data I'd like to unlock and b) I'd like to share my code with others and prevent them from repeating the process by hand.

I have both WinRAR and 7-zip installed on my computer, and I can individually open these files easily with either program.

I've looked around at the `unzip` `untar` and `unz` commands, but I don't believe any of them do what I need.

I don't know anything about compression, but if it makes any difference: each of these files only contains *one* file and it's *just a text file*.

I would strongly prefer a solution that does not require the user to install additional software (like WinRAR or 7-Zip) and execute a command with `shell`, although I acknowledge this task might be impossible with just R and CRAN packages.  I actually believe running `shell.exec` on these files with additional parameters might work on computers with WinRAR installed, but again, I'd like to avoid that installation if possible.  :)

Running the code below will load the files I am trying to extract -- the .7z files in `files.data` are what needs to be unlocked.

```
# create a temporary file and temporary directory, download the file, extract the file to the temporary directory
tf <- tempfile() ; td <- tempdir()
file.path <- "ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Orcamentos_Familiares/Pesquisa_de_Orcamentos_Familiares_2008_2009/Microdados/Dados.zip"
download.file( file.path , tf , mode = "wb" )
files.data <- unzip( tf , exdir = td )

# how do i unzip ANY of these .7z files?
files.data
```

Thanks!!! :)

Comment: The best solution would be a package that could read and write 7z files using either the standard connection API or via temporary files on disk. But I don't think that package exists.

Comment: agreed.  now i'm petitioning the folks at the brazilian census to follow @dirk's advice and re-post the files with a standard format :)  thanks hadley!

Comment: the example your showing is a pkzip compresse file not a p7 compressed file. So your standard `unzip()` would work. A related question would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146263/sys-glob-within-unzip

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have `7z` executable in your path, you can simple use `system` command

`system('7z e -o <output_dir> <archive_name>')`

Comment: Completely misses the requirement of "I would strongly prefer a solution that does not require the user to install additional software".

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel but short of doing everything by hand, it's the only thing that works, right?  :(

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel ..from what you and hadley are saying, it's the _only_ answer. :( why would i delete the thread?  others might also benefit from knowing this task is impossible without installing external software

Comment: note that the command is `system('7z e -o<output_dir> <archive_name>')`. With a space between -o and the directory it fails!

Answer (score 33):

This can be done with the [`archive` package](https://github.com/jimhester/archive).

```
library(archive)
tf <- tempfile() ; td <- tempdir()
file.path <- "ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Orcamentos_Familiares/Pesquisa_de_Orcamentos_Familiares_2008_2009/Microdados/Dados.zip"
download.file( file.path , tf , mode = "wb" )
archive(tf)
```

See https://github.com/jimhester/archive

Comment: amazing.  i'll start dumping 7-zip dependencies right away.  https://github.com/ajdamico/lodown/issues/99  thank you

Comment: `archive_extract` for extraction.

Comment: Thank you! For compression [`archive_write_dir()`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/11/archive-1-1-2/) works effectively.