# download of zipped file from CDC ftp site with R gets corrupted no matter what download method used

Tags: r, curl, ftp, download, httr

trying to download this zipped file from the cdc with R.  it works fine from firefox.. so i tried `setInternet2(TRUE)` right away, but that still didn't work..

in every case below, i get:

> z<-unzip(tf)

```
Warning message:
In unzip(tf) : zip file is corrupt
```

here are the starting two lines for all of my attempts--

```
fn <- 'ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/health_statistics/nchs/datasets/dvs/natality/nat2012us.zip'
tf <- tempfile() ; td <- tempdir()
```

and here's what i tried:

```
# fails
download.file(fn,tf,mode='wb')
z <- unzip( tf , exdir = td )

# fails
setInternet2(TRUE)
download.file(fn,tf,mode='wb')
z <- unzip( tf , exdir = td )

# fails
download.file(fn,tf,mode='wb',cacheOK=FALSE)
z <- unzip( tf , exdir = td )

# fails
setInternet2(TRUE)
download.file(fn,tf,mode='wb',cacheOK=FALSE)
z <- unzip( tf , exdir = td )

# fails
library(downloader)
download(fn,tf,mode='wb')
z <- unzip( tf , exdir = td )

# fails
library(httr)
resp <- GET(fn)
writeBin(content(resp, "raw"), tf)

# fails
library(RCurl)
x <- getBinaryURL( fn )
writeBin( x , tf )
z <- unzip(tf)


# in every case:
> file.info(tf)$size
[1] 228799759
```

sorry if it's something stupid

Comment: Have you got a smaller example file it fails on? Or a smaller example it works on? 200Mb is a bit of a download... Also a big WARNING 200Mb file!!! would have been appreciated!

Comment: If you download with R and try and unzip in Windows does Windows say its corrupt? In other words, is it R's download that's getting it wrong or R's unzip? Zip compression can have many compression algorithms, and maybe R's unzip doesn't have the One.

Comment: @Spacedman i don't sorry.  this problem appears to be windows compression in R, and it's similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096192/how-to-programmatically-extract-or-unzip-a-7z-7-zip-file-with-r

Comment: Yeah, help(unzip) is pretty confessional about how dysfunctional it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks windows `unzip="internal"` is the problem.  `shell()` and winrar work around the problem

```
fn <- 'ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/health_statistics/nchs/datasets/dvs/natality/nat2012us.zip'
tf <- tempfile()
download.file( fn , tf , mode = 'wb' )

wr <- normalizePath( "C:/Program Files/WinRAR/WinRAR.exe" )

td <- tempdir()
shell( paste0( '"' , wr , '" x ' , tf , ' ' , td ) )
```